# Jsoup accessing div tag under table tag not working

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

Can some one help me with this. This is suppose to return 4 elements but it returns 0.

```
            Document mDoc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(documents[0]).openStream(), "UTF-8", BASE_URL);

            // get main root
            Elements mBannerRoot = mDoc.getElementsByClass("bl_me_main");

            mExMessage = String.valueOf(mBannerRoot.size());
```

Here is the URL:
http://www.xboxachievements.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with the following two methods:

```
String url = "http://www.xboxachievements.com/";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements methodOne = doc.select("div.bl_me_main");
Elements methodTwo = doc.getElementsByClass("bl_me_main");

System.out.println(methodOne.size());
System.out.println(methodTwo.size());
```

It outputs `5` for the size of each though, not 4 as you expected.

So perhaps something is going wrong in the first line (`Document mDoc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(documents[0]).openStream(), "UTF-8", BASE_URL);`).

Comment: Thanks, I did had a different url. i spend a whole day trying to figure that out. lol.